# How do I map attached image like data in sqlite tables with minimal redundancy?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

[image]

I can only think of a table structure like this:

from                 To                    fare
Dilshad garden     Dilshad garden          8
Dilshad garden     Jhil mil                8
Dilshad garden     Mansrover park          10
Dilshad garden     shahdara                10
Dilshad garden     Welcome                 12

same as 4 more tables would be created for each station.Buts that too redundant and time consuming for me. I have  200 stations in my model.Here i have just shown five stations.

Please help me ..

Answer (score 2):

stations

```
|- id -|-       Name     -|
|-  1 -|- Dilshad Garden -|
|-  2 -|- Jhil mil       -|
|-  3 -|- Mansrover Park -|
|-  4 -|- Shahdara       -|
|-  5 -|- Welcome        -|
```

fares

```
|- from -|- to -|- fare -|
|-    1 -|-  1 -|-    8 -|
|-    1 -|-  2 -|-    8 -|
|-    1 -|-  3 -|-   10 -|
|-    1 -|-  4 -|-   10 -|
|-    1 -|-  5 -|-   12 -|
|-    2 -|-  2 -|-    8 -|
|-    2 -|-  3 -|-    8 -|
|-    2 -|-  4 -|-   10 -|
|-    2 -|-  5 -|-   10 -|
|-    3 -|-  3 -|-    8 -|
|-    3 -|-  4 -|-    8 -|
|-    3 -|-  5 -|-   10 -|
|-    4 -|-  4 -|-    8 -|
|-    4 -|-  5 -|-    8 -|
|-    5 -|-  5 -|-    8 -|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a 2 table structure :

One with each station, and giving an id for each, like

```
StationID 
Station_Name
```

and the second one like

```
Station_A   
Station_B
Fare
```

Since the fare from A to B is the same as B to A, it requires only one entry in the table.
While querying, check for the station ids in both A and B to get your fare.